# Back propagation on a simple function

Tags: neural-network

I'm trying to run a back propagation to learn a simple function. I'm not sure what criteria decides the number of hidden layers and so forth. E.g, for a function like f(x)= x^4 - 15x^2; -5<=x<=+5, I'm guessing each of the x values will be used as inputs (please correct me if I'm wrong) to find the output before an error is propagated back. But what determines if there should be any hidden layers?

Comment: Non linear functions cannot be solved by a single layer. The complexity of the function is proportional to the size of the hidden layer

Comment: Okay. But will determine the number of inputs and what inputs to use, or would that just be on a trial basis